# Access form DoCmd.ApplyFilter with If Statemnent

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to have an If statement contained within DoCmd.ApplyFilter?

I have a continuous form that includes the category columns EmployeeTypeID (1 (Field), 2 (Office)) and DepartmentID (1 (New Sales), 2(Service), 3(Other)). I want to be able to filter the DepartmentID to only show the records containing Other just for Office while showing all departments for Field.

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "(dbo_Stat.DepartmentID)=3"
```

That works to filter everything

```
DoCmd.AppplyFilter, "IF(dbo_Stat.EmployeeTypeID)=2 Then (dbo_Stat.DepartmentID)=3
```

That is what I want to achieve, however the syntax doesn't seem right. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

```
DoCmd.AppplyFilter, "dbo_Stat.DepartmentID = IIf(dbo_Stat.EmployeeTypeID = 2, 3, SomeOtherValueThan3)"
```

For a "match all", you could try the old trick:

```
DoCmd.AppplyFilter, "dbo_Stat.DepartmentID = IIf(dbo_Stat.EmployeeTypeID = 2, 3, dbo_Stat.DepartmentID)"
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is there a way to use a wildcard in the "Else" section? I tried DoCmd.AppplyFilter, "dbo_Stat.DepartmentID = IIf(dbo_Stat.EmployeeTypeID = 2, 3, " * ")" and got a type mismatch. The field in question is a tinyint.